# Mouse Click not working for google.maps.places.Autocomplete

Tags: javascript, jquery, ember.js, google-places, google-places-autocomplete

I have an issue with google.maps.places.Autocomplete, strangely the same code is working OK on another page with all other similar assets except the input control is in a div that is displayed using slick slider on the page where i am having the issue . On this page I still can use keyboard keys to select the search results. But when I try to left click using mouse on search results, it do not change any thing infact the result div is not being hidden if I click some where else on page. Somehow Google Api is not binding click events to Search Results when input control is in sliding div.

Following is my code. Please help.

```
 var _g_autocomplete;
function initializeGoogleSearch() {
  var crtlId = 'txtSearchInput';
  _g_autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(
      /** @type {HTMLInputElement} */(document.getElementById(crtlId)),
      { types: ['geocode'] });
  google.maps.event.addListener(_g_autocomplete, 'place_changed', function() {
  var place = _g_autocomplete.getPlace();
    //console.log(place);
  });

}
```

Comment: Maybe a `z-index` issue, where there's a `div` overlaying your controls, and clicks are not getting through?  `pointer-events: none` which will [allow clicks to pass through a layer](https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/p/pointer-events/) might be useful?  If your code works on another page, then it isn't the problem - it's a clash, most likely with the slider as you describe. So we need to see that, maybe try creating a JSFiddle.

Comment: I debugged about that & found that Mouse hover is reflecting in search result items, when I hover any item then it's background colour is changed a bit like on other pages, but only Click event is not firing on search result items.

Comment: So maybe your slider is catching clicks and not allowing them through?

Comment: That may be possible, infect this is the case but I am not sure how to solve this issue.

Comment: But the same time on other html elements like buttons are clickable in same div.

Comment: Currently have the same problem, is this solved yet?